# Resize group of lines in visio

Tags: resize, visio

I have created several lines and arcs in Microsoft Visio, and then I grouped them. When I tried to re-size them, they lose their proportions. 
I have tried to solve the problem by selecting 'Aspect ratio' in the Protection menu, but it does not work. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Visio 2010, without locking aspect ratio or any other special steps.  What version of Visio are you using?

Comment: My guess is that this was a bug fix and your best bet would be to upgrade to Visio 2010 (or 2013).  If that isn't an option, try creating an invisible 2-D shape (e.g. a rectangle with no fill and no visible geometry), and glue the lines to parts of that rectangle.

Comment: It is the company version, so I cannot upgrade it.
I have tried the box idea, but is does not work. Anyway, thank you for your time.